# How to make a list of all possible permutations?

Tags: python, list, permutation

Is there a function that generates all the permutations of a list of lists, while keeping their orders?

For example:

```
func([[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]])
```

produces:

```
[[1, 10], [1, 20], [1, 30], [2, 10], [2, 20], [2, 30], [3, 10], [3, 20], [3, 30]]
```

Comment: What did you find so far when you searched for such a function? Have you seen the `itertools` module in the Python standard library already?

Comment: By the way, what you have shown as an example is called "cartesian product", not "permutations".

Comment: You are looking for `itertools.product`, not`permutations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `product` function in itertools module which does exactly that :

```
from itertools import product

lst = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]
res = [list(i) for i in product(*lst)]
print(res)
```

Because you want the inside items to be list as well, I used `list(i)` to convert the tuple which `product` gives into list.

Output:

`[[1, 10], [1, 20], [1, 30], [2, 10], [2, 20], [2, 30], [3, 10], [3, 20], [3, 30]]`